# Bash code runs correctly when it is executed in terminal but does not work properly when executed using udev

Tags: linux, bash, udev

I am trying to move various files present in a pendrive into their respective folders on PC. ie ,Music files into music folder,text files into Documents and so on..
I have written a script for that and it is working fine(all files are being moved into their respective folders) when I execute by typing ./cpphone.sh but when I use a udev rule the script not executing correctly (No files are being moved into their folders) however the echo's are being stored into the file testlog.txt. So the script is being executed but files are not being moved.Why is it so?. Script is owned by the root.

My Udev rule is ACTION=="add", RUN+="/lib/udev/cpphone.sh"

My script is

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo Hello > /home/ArunReddy/testlog.txt
    exec 1>/dev/null 2>&1  
    DIR=$(date +%d-%m-%y) 

    if [ ! -d /home/ArunReddy/Pictures/"$DIR" ];
    then
        cd /home/ArunReddy/Pictures/
    mkdir $DIR
    fi

    if [ ! -d /home/ArunReddy/Pictures/"$DIR" ];
    then
    cd /home/ArunReddy/Documents/
        mkdir $DIR
    fi

    if [ ! -d /home/ArunReddy/Videos/"$DIR" ];
    then
    cd /home/ArunReddy/Videos/
    mkdir $DIR
    fi

    if [ ! -d /home/ArunReddy/Music/"$DIR" ];
    then
    cd /home/ArunReddy/Music/
    mkdir $DIR
    fi

    cd /run/media/ArunReddy/121C-E137
    mv *.png /home/ArunReddy/Pictures/$DIR/
    echo pngfilecmd executed>/home/ArunReddy/testlog.txt
    mv *.jpg /home/ArunReddy/Pictures/$DIR/
    mv *.bmp /home/ArunReddy/Pictures/$DIR/
    mv *.txt /home/ArunReddy/Documents/$DIR/
    mv *.odt /home/ArunReddy/Documents/$DIR/
    mv *.doc /home/ArunReddy/Documents/$DIR/
    mv *.pptx /home/ArunReddy/Documents/$DIR/
    mv *.pdf /home/ArunReddy/Documents/$DIR/
    mv *.ppt /home/ArunReddy/Documents/$DIR/
    mv *.docx /home/ArunReddy/Documents/$DIR/
    mv *.avi /home/ArunReddy/Videos/$DIR/
    mv *.flv /home/ArunReddy/Videos/$DIR/
    mv *.MP4 /home/ArunReddy/Videos/$DIR/
    mv *.mpeg /home/ArunReddy/Videos/$DIR/
    mv *.MP3 /home/ArunReddy/Music/$DIR/
    exit
```

Comment: I would guess it's a permissions issue. Please add `2>> /home/ArunReddy/error` to each of the `mv commands. For example `mv *.jpg /home/ArunReddy/Pictures/$DIR/ 2>> /home/ArunReddy/error`. That will capture any error messages printed. Have a look at the resulting `~ArunReddy/error` file and [edit] your question to include the errors.

Comment: What happens if there are no files with the extensions you listed? answer: it's an error. Is this the behavior you're expecting?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf It will generate an error if there are no files with the extensions are present but I have hidden all the error messages it generates

Comment: Remove the `exec 1>/dev/null 2>&1` part, enclose your full script (well, starting from the line below the `#!/bin/bash`) into `{ ... } &> /home/ArunReddy/error`. This will log the stdout and stderr of your script into the file `/home/ArunReddy/error` so that you can analyze the errors.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf It shows that the directory for my pendrive is invalid

Comment: You mean `bash: cd: /run/media/ArunReddy/121C-E137: No such file or directory`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf    YES, But when I run the command in terminal it executes

Comment: Is your pendrive really mounted at this point, then?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes I ran cd /run/media/ArunReddy/121C-E137 in the terminal and their was no problem

Comment: I don't know udev very well, but at least you now have a clue about the error. Modify your question to specify all this. Good luck!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Iam really really thankful for you help, Thank you :)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I think the problem is that the pendrive is not completed mounted and ready for use when the cd /run... line is being executed so I need to make the script wait till the directory is available

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the udev environment that executes those scripts has no PATH defined. Try to use full paths to `cd`, `mkdir`, `cp` etc. commands. You can find out the paths using for example with `which cd` command in shell.

Comment: No,doesn't work :(. But thanks for the help